# jsonb_each function Returns null values Not Castable To null::INT

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, jsonb, postgresql-10

Let me explain:

[1] [no error]

```
SELECT (('{"a": null}'::JSONB)->>'a')::INT;
```

[2] [error here]

```
SELECT (t.value::TEXT)::INT FROM jsonb_each(('{"a": null}'::JSONB)) AS t
```

- I have to use jsonb_each function.
- How can i make SQL number 2 return null?

Comment: PostgreSQL version: "PostgreSQL 10.12"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you use `->>` which returns the value as a `text` data type. The equivalent "for each" function is `jsonb_each_text()` which also returns the value as `text`. `jsonb_each` returns each value as a JSONB value

```
SELECT t.value::INT 
FROM jsonb_each_text(('{"a": null}'::JSONB)) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example:

```
SELECT nullif(t.value::text,'null')::int
FROM jsonb_each(('{"a": null}'::JSONB)) AS t
```

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Both answers are better than mine. I tried to use row_to_json. I will accept the native one. Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  @a_horse_without_name does this the right way - as usually.  I used jsonb_each as you specified you needed to use that function for some reason :-)